# How can I call a tag and display in descending (newest first) order?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, content-management-system

I am trying to get a page displaying posts (on Wolf CMS) in descending order, and I think I am breaking the code by how I am using my "if" statements. If I remove the first one the page displays fine, but not in the right order. It will appear in ascending order. Here is my code, can anyone spot the dysfunction I have with it?:

```
    <?php $findTag = 'dinorun'; 
    $mychildren = $this->findById(4)->children(); 
    if ($mychildren->childrenCount() > 0) {
    $last_articles = $mychildren->children(array('limit'=>10, 'order'=>'page.created_on DESC'));
     foreach ($last_articles as $child) : 
    $childTags = join(',', $child->tags()); 
   if (strpos($childTags, $findTag) !== FALSE) : 
   ?>
    <ul class="blogpage">
     <?php echo $child->content(); 
      echo "<div class='postend'></div></ul>"; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; 

    ?>
```

**Edit:** I actually didn't have that extra ; that was a mistake. Removing it made no change.

Here is the original code I was using that displayed everything in ascending order:

```
<?php $findTag = 'dinorun'; ?>
<?php $children = $this->findById(4)->children(); ?>
<ul class="blogpage">
<?php foreach ($children as $child) : ?>
<?php $childTags = join(',', $child->tags()); ?>
<?php if (strpos($childTags, $findTag) !== FALSE) : ?>
<?php; echo $child->content(); 
echo "<div class='postend'></div></ul>"; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove semi colon into

try this

```
<?php $findTag = 'dinorun'; 
    $mychildren = $this->findById(4)->children(); 
    if ($mychildren->childrenCount() > 0) {
    $last_articles = $mychildren->children(array('limit'=>10, 'order'=>'page.created_on DESC'));
     foreach ($last_articles as $child) : 
    $childTags = join(',', $child->tags()); 
   if (strpos($childTags, $findTag) !== FALSE) : 
?>
    <ul class="blogpage">
     <?php echo $child->content(); 
      echo "<div class='postend'></div></ul>"; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; 

    ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the extra semicolon was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
    <?php $findTag = 'dinorun'; ?>
<?php $mychildren = $this->findById(4)->children(); 
if ($mychildren->childrenCount() > 0) {
    $last_articles = $mychildren->children(array('limit'=>10, 'order'=>'page.created_on DESC'));
    ?>
<?php foreach ($last_articles as $child) : ?>
<?php $childTags = join(',', $child->tags()); ?>
<?php if (strpos($childTags, $findTag) !== FALSE) : ?>
<ul class="blogpage">
    <?php 
        echo $child->content(); 
        echo "<div class='postend'></div></ul>"; 
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: This removes the error I am getting in the editor, but does not resolve my problem. It seems to not be displaying any articles. I will update the above post with the original code that displayed articles, but displayed them in ascending order.